# Notice: Array to string conversion Error: Array

Tags: php, arrays, sqlsrv

This one has had me stumped for a while I cannot see why I am getting this error. This is my code

```
<?php
include('include/auth.php');
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

    $serverName = "localhost";
    $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"db", "UID"=>"sa", "PWD"=>"****");
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo );
    if( $conn === false ) {
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }


    $pathfinderid = $_POST['pathfinderid'];
    $locationid = $_POST['locationid'];
    $status = $_POST['status'];
    $statusnote = $_POST['statusnote'];
    $user = $_SESSION['SESS_USER'];
    $date = new DateTime();
    $ims = 'New Device Added';

    if(empty($pathfinderid) || empty($locationid) || empty($status) || empty($statusnote)) {
        echo "<div id='source'><p style='color:red;'>Please complete all fields</p></div>";
    }
    else
    {   
        //SQL to check if pathdnder exsists
        $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, "SELECT * FROM devices WHERE pathfinderid='$pathfinderid'");
        //If statement to check rows
        if ($stmt) {
            $rows = sqlsrv_has_rows( $stmt );

            if ($rows === true) {
                echo "<div id='source'><p style='color:red';>PathfinderID already exists</div>";
            }
            else 
            {
                //Insert in to Devices Table
                $tsql="INSERT INTO devices (pathfinderid, locationid, addeddate, status, creation_date, status_note) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                $var = array ($pathfinderid, $locationid, $date, $status, $date, $statusnote);
                if (!sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql, $var)) {
                    die('Error: ' . sqlsrv_errors());
                }
                //Insert in to Transaction Log
                $tsql="INSERT INTO transaction_log (Date, IMS, PathfinderID, LocationID, TransactionNotes, ManagedBy) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                $var = array ($date, $ims, $pathfinderid, $locationid, $statusnote, $statusnote, $user);
                if (!sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql, $var)) {
                    die('Error: ' . sqlsrv_errors());
                }
                //Insert in to Movment Log
                $tsql="INSERT INTO movement_log (pathfinderid, locationid, status, update_timestamp, addeddate, status_note) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?')";
                $var = array ($pathfinderid, $locationid, $status, $date, $date, $statusnote);
                if (!sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql, $var)) {
                    die('Error: ' . sqlsrv_errors());
                }
                //Display the confirmation messgae
                echo "<div id='source'><p style='color:green;'>Device Added</p></div>";

            }
        }


    }
}
```

?>

The error is flagging as beng on line 52 which is:

```
//Insert in to Transaction Log
                $tsql="INSERT INTO transaction_log (Date, IMS, PathfinderID, LocationID, TransactionNotes, ManagedBy) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                $var = array ($date, $ims, $pathfinderid, $locationid, $statusnote, $statusnote, $user);
                if (!sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql, $var)) {
                    die('Error: ' . sqlsrv_errors());
                }
```

Any ideas? The only thing I can think is if it is because I am reusing variable names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a double variable ($statusnote)

```
       //Insert in to Transaction Log
        $tsql="INSERT INTO transaction_log (Date, IMS, PathfinderID, LocationID, TransactionNotes, ManagedBy) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        $var = array ($date, $ims, $pathfinderid, $locationid, $statusnote, $statusnote, $user);
        if (!sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql, $var)) {
            die('Error: ' . sqlsrv_errors());
        }
```

should be

```
       //Insert in to Transaction Log
        $tsql="INSERT INTO transaction_log (Date, IMS, PathfinderID, LocationID, TransactionNotes, ManagedBy) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        $var = array ($date, $ims, $pathfinderid, $locationid, $statusnote, $user);
        if (!sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql, $var)) {
            die('Error: ' . sqlsrv_errors());
        }
```

Comment: There's also an extra placeholder question-mark in the values.

Comment: yes, so either the variable has to be some other variable or things got out of sync by copy paste of code